# The differences amongst f[x_], f[x__], and f[x___]

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

This is probably very elementary but I have not used the following and I cannot find anything online, and I was unable to find something here.

Can someone explain to me the differences amongst

```
f[x_]:=, f[x__]:=, f[x___]:=
```

and maybe give some practical examples so I can see the differences?

Comment: Consider `g1[x_]:= {x}`, `g2[x__]:= {x}`, and `g3[x___]:={x}` and compare `g1[]`, `g1[5]` and `g1[5,6]` (similarly for `g2` and `g3`).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Some more questions. When I tried g3[5, 6, 7] it gave me {5,6,7} which is what I expected from the general pattern. However, g2[5, 6, 7] also gives the same result, so I am not sure what's the difference. Also g1[], g2[], just give back the same while g3[] gives back {}. Could you explain a bit more thoroughly? Am I missing something?

Comment: Konstantinos, see [`Blank (_)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html), [`BlankSequence (__)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html) and [`BlankNullSequence (___)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) in the docs for more details. `g1` requires a single argument; so `g1[]` and `g1[2,3]` both return unevaluated. `g2` requires _1 or more_ arguments so `g2[]` returns `g2[]`; and ...

Comment: ... `g3` expects _0 or more_ arguments so `g3[]`  evaluates to  `{}`, `g3[1,2,3]` gives `{1,2,3}`and  `g3[{1,2,3}]` (one argument which is the list `{1,2,3}`) gives `{{1,2,3}}` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot once more. I did not know how to find these online. I was trying something like f[__] Mathematica and nothing was popping up.

Comment: Worth knowing, for future reference, that the online *Mathematica* documentation search will find the correct entries for special forms such as `___` or `_` or any of the other squiggles regularly encountered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`_` matches one thing.

`__` matches one or more things.

`___` matches zero or more things.